# Mysql use 2 functions in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause, spatial

I'm trying to use 2 same functions in 1 query which is this

```
    select *,  ST_Distance_Sphere( point(
                31.00000, 35.00000),
                point(latitude_0, longitude_0)) * .0001
                as `distance_in_km` ,

          ST_Distance_Sphere( point (
                31.00000, 35.00000),
                point(dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0)) * .0001
                as `distance_in_km`

               from `most_places_used` 
                having `distance_in_km` <= '0.001' 
order by `distance_in_km` asc Limit 1
```

This uses only the first function and give right result for the first latlngs only.

I need the row which is almost near to the 2 latlngs (the latlngs is just example don't care if it's wrong <3 ) I want it to Give me the row that equals the functions suppose to be the functions latlngs near for the 4 column latlngs

This is the column names.. as in the function ST_Distance_Sphere

```
(latitude_0, longitude_0, dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0)
```

I need something similar to this query do the same need or the fix for it <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the same alias to two different columns, which makes your query ambiguous about which one you want to use to filter and order. I would recommend two different aliases and `least()` instead:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        mpu.*,  
        ST_Distance_Sphere( 
            point(31.00000, 35.00000),
            point(latitude_0, longitude_0)
        ) * 0.0001 as distance_in_km1,
        ST_Distance_Sphere( 
            point (31.00000, 35.00000),
            point(dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0)
        ) * 0.0001 as distance_in_km2
    from most_places_used mpu
) t
where least (distance_in_km1, distance_in_km2) <= 0.001
order by least (distance_in_km1, distance_in_km2)
limit 1
```

Note that I used a subquery rather than a `having` clause: this is a more standard and readable way to proceed, for no performance penalty anyway.

If you don't need to differentiate the two computations in the resultset, you can move `least()` directly to the subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        mpu.*,  
        least(
            ST_Distance_Sphere( 
                point(31.00000, 35.00000),
                point(latitude_0, longitude_0)
            ),
            ST_Distance_Sphere( 
                point (31.00000, 35.00000),
                point(dest_latitude_0, dest_longitude_0)
            )
        ) * 0.0001 as distance_in_km
    from most_places_used mpu
) t
where distance_in_km <= 0.001
order by distance_in_km
limit 1
```

Comment: Bro Thank you so much was searching these 5 months to only this simple I was searching too much on the internet for anything similar, !! I'm sorry, not MySQL user that's why thank you so so so much! <3